# my button is not getting rounded/smooth using the code in my kv file

Tags: button, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to get my button to be round but it stays rectangular, and if it makes any difference I have a dark cls theme for my app

this is my kv file code:

```
<FourthWindow>:
name: "tags"
FloatLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height
    SmoothButton:
        id: bedtime
        text: "Time for bed"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
        text_size: self.width, self.height
        halign:'center'
        valign: 'center'
        font_size: self.height - dp(15)

<SmoothButton@Button>:
background_color: (0,.5,.75,1)
background_normal: ''
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: (0,.5,.75,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [18]
```